# Unity: player acts weirdly when I release movement input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Good day everyone!

I was trying to make my player face the direction he's walking towards, but then weird things started happening. Whenever I now let go of my input keys, the player slowly gets sucked to his local z-axis. Sometimes he does this while standing up, sometimes he does this flipped.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

I'll provide you with my script:

```
public class JackMovement3D : MonoBehaviour {

 public float speed = 6.0F;
 public float VerticalSpeed = 10f;
 public float HorizontalSpeed = 60f;
 public float rotationSpeed = 5f;
 public float jumpSpeed = 8.0F;
 public float gravity = 20.0F;

 private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
 private Animator animator;

 private void Start()
 {
     animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
 }

 void Update()
 {
     CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
     // is the controller on the ground?
     if (controller.isGrounded)
     {
         float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * HorizontalSpeed;
         float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * VerticalSpeed;

         //Feed moveDirection with input.
         moveDirection = new Vector3(horizontal, 0, vertical);
         moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);

         //Multiply it by speed.
         moveDirection *= speed;
     }

     //Applying gravity to the controller
     moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;

     animator.SetFloat("Blend", controller.velocity.magnitude);

     //Look at walking direction
     Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(moveDirection);
     transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, newRotation, rotationSpeed);

     // CharacterController.Move to move the player in target direction
     controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
 }

 private void LateUpdate()
 {
     transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, transform.localEulerAngles.y, transform.localEulerAngles.z);
 }
```

}

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue but `Quaternion.LookRotation(moveDirection);` might be an issue for a `Vector3(0,0,0)` which would be the one you get if there is no Input ... `Returns identity if forward or upwards magnitude is zero.` so this might return you to a kind of idle rotation .. not sure if this is desired

Comment: Hmm okay, so I think the problem indeed is with the `newRotation` variable. I can't seem to figure out what value to give it so it will make my player face the direction he's walking towards.

Comment: Well you could e.g. check `if(Mathf.Approximately(moveDirection.sqrMagnitude, 0)) return;` so it only continues with setting a rotation and movement if there actually is any input. Otherwise it would simply stay on its last assigned rotation

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the issue you describe but it might be related to

```
Quaternion.LookRotation(moveDirection);
```

since if there is no Input the `moveDirection` is a `Vector3(0,0,0)` and [`Quaternion.LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html)

> Returns identity if forward or upwards magnitude is zero.

so you could probably avoid that resetting the rotation to idendity by adding a check like

```
// if movement is 0 do nothing else
if(Mathf.Approximately(moveDirection.sqrMagnitude, 0)) return;
```

this should be before adding the gravity.

Actually not sure again but I guess the gravity should be added after

```
 void Update()
 {
     CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
     // is the controller on the ground?
     if (controller.isGrounded)
     {
         float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * HorizontalSpeed;
         float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * VerticalSpeed;

         //Feed moveDirection with input.
         moveDirection = new Vector3(horizontal, 0, vertical);
         moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);

         //Multiply it by speed.
         moveDirection *= speed;
     }

     animator.SetFloat("Blend", controller.velocity.magnitude);

     // if movement is 0 do nothing else
     if(Mathf.Approximately(moveDirection.sqrMagnitude, 0))
     {
         return;
     }

     moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;

     //Look at walking direction
     var newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(moveDirection);
     transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, newRotation, rotationSpeed);

     // CharacterController.Move to move the player in target direction
     controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but whenever I move the gravity code my player can't seem to start moving.